# Trouble opening file C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to open a binary database with this code

```
Store::Store(const char* filename)
{
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
if(!inFile){
    cout << "Could not open file " << data << "!" << endl;
}

while( inFile ){
inFile.read((char*) this, sizeof(Store));
}

inFile.close();
```

The error I getting is the "Could not open file" error, and I am pretty stumped.

Comment: Does the filename specified exist in the current directory?

Comment: Is the path to the file correct? Is the filename correctly spelled?

Comment: One big "gotcha" is that some dev environments like Visual Studio set your directory to your project directory instead of the location of the .exe, so when you debug it searches next to the project file which can seem confusing.

Comment: change `if(!inFile)` to `if(!inFile.isOpen())` and see if it works or not. You also need to make sure that the file does exist. check this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/) for more information of the `isOpen()` funcction.

Comment: The path and name are all correct, but I'm trying to pass in a file that is a symbolic link to the file from my professor. It could be he messed up, so I'm going to go send some emails

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `data` was probably supposed to be `filename`.

The likeliest reason is that the working directory of your application is not where you think it is, and the file does not exist. Try with an absolute path to check if this is the case.

Not related to the question: this way of 'saving' the  object is very unsafe and highly dependent on the way how your compiler arranges `Store` instances in memory. The saved stores are most likely not compatible with versions of the program compiled with other compilers, and potentially not even with different builds from the same compiler.

If `Store` has virtual members, you are practically guaranteed to crash. Technically, it is undefined behaviour anyway.

You should look into serialising not the whole objects, but only the raw data parts of your database. A look into `boost.serialization` may be helpful.

Comment: I serialize whole objects without problems but not using the serialization library in Boost.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears correct for accessing the file, I would make sure the file path is correct especially if it is a relative path. You might be in the wrong working directory. Also you may not possess the require permissions to read the file, try running with admin/root privileges (which usually isn't the case with reading a file, but worth mentioning).

I would print out the working directory and the file name to make sure everything is being referenced correctly.